# R win-builder fails silently

Tags: r, cran, r-package

I am testing a package with [win-builder](https://win-builder.r-project.org) (R-release), and the package checks fail without returning a real error message. These same checks work fine locally on Windows and Linux for R 3.3.2 and 3.2.0. I have no compiled code, just uncompiled R code, and I do not redirect output anywhere.

```
** running tests for arch 'i386' ... ERROR
Running the tests in 'tests/testthat.R' failed.
Last 13 lines of output:

 R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
  Type 'contributors()' for more information and
  'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
  'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
  Type 'q()' to quit R.

  > library(testthat)
  > library(mypackage)
  > 
  > test_check("mypackage")
** running tests for arch 'x64' ... [109s] OK
  Running 'testthat.R' [108s]
```

I checked the bottom of testthat.Rout.fail, and it really does end with test_check("mypackage").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. The R session was crashing. Reproduced, debugged, and fixed locally on i386.